# how to implement pow(double x, double y)?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I know how to impelment pow(double x, int y)

```
public class Solution {
    public double myPow(double x, int n) {
        if (n == 0)
            return 1;

        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return myPow(x * x, n / 2);
        } else {
            if (n > 0)
                return x * myPow(x, n - 1);
            else
                return 1 / x * myPow(x, n + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

But how to make it handle double y?

Comment: ah, sorry, copied wrong code piece. Corrected now.

Comment: I once had an entire library that would do such calculations based on series expansion, need to see if I still have it.

Comment: This isn't really a programming problem. It's a (hard) maths problem. You can simplify it if you know that (for x, y > 0), x^y is equal to exp(y log x), but that doesn't really solve the problem as you then need to know how to program exp and log.

Comment: Why are you interested in using `double` in the first place which causes severe precision errors in turn?

Comment: That depends a lot on what you allow yourself to do. Anything from just using a library function for that to implementing the floating point arithmetics...

Comment: @Tiny `double` doesn't cause severe precision errors - double has 53 bits mantissa (which is about 16 digits). 16 digits precision is quite high precision and should be enough for most applications.

Comment: You can take a look at the native code from the OpenJDK implementation: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/native/java/lang/fdlibm/src/e_pow.c.

Comment: @Tiny this is a G*****  phone interview question for SWE.

Comment: @pbabcdefp: How to implement `pow` is very much a programming problem.  "Reducing" via `exp(expo*log(base))` doesn't help as much as you'd think because it forces you to compute `exp` and `log` to more precision than you have.

Comment: @tmyklebu That's true, but we can see from the question that the OP doesn't actually require the closest double to the true mathematical value of x^y, because the solution given for y an integer uses repeated multiplication which will introduce rounding errors. So in the spirit of the question, I think using exp and log is close enough. I know that `Math.pow` really uses native code. Do you know how it works?

Comment: I have implemented `pow(double,double)` for a shipping math library. In practical terms, one needs to compute `log(x)` and `y*log(x)` with extra precision (e.g as a double-double). Unless a faithfully-rounded result is required, regular `exp()` will suffice since `exp(hi+lo)` ~= `exp(hi) + lo * exp(hi)` if `lo` much smaller in magnitude than `hi`; this can be computed with a single `fma()`. In addition, a fair amount of special case handling is required to conform to C/C++ language standards. Overall the question is so broad that a detailed answer far exceeds the usual Stackoverflow format.

Comment: If you are interested I wrote such a library to get behind these things. It's written in Java, here is it's github: [github.com](https://github.com/manuel-fede/c)

Comment: If you're still interested in this - you could read the code of the open source Apfloat for Java library - they are doing this for arbitrary precision floating point numbers, but the same principle can be used for double.

Answer (score 1):

Exponentiation with non-integer values is done mathematically with infinite series:

[See here under "Exponential Series Expansion" and "Exponential Theorem"](http://math.tutorvista.com/discrete-math/exponential-series.html)

Basically, you'll use a known infinite series of terms, and calculate a number of them that satisfies your numerical precision requirements.

Answer (score -2):

If i recall correctly you need to write a series expansion for log (natural logarithm) and exp (exponent).
Since
log(x^y) = y*log(x) and
exp(log(x)) = x
you can evaluate the result. I think I used the Taylor series for this.
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)

Comment: this does not work for negative x. he would need a complex number library to deal with the branches of ln for negative inputs

Comment: I'll upload my project to [Github](github.com) this does also support (more or less) complex numbers.